# Angular.js Fail to Compile error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to install fire-base to my angular project using bower and it told me to try using `!firebase#3.9.0` but its not working.

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Here is the error below:

> Unable to find a suitable version for firebase, please choose one by
>   typing one of the numbers below:
>       1) firebase#3.x.x which resolved to 3.9.0 and is required by angularfire#2.3.0
>       2) firebase#^4.2.0 which resolved to 4.2.0 Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you specify dependencies for you app via Bower, some of the packages might rely on different versions of the same library. You will have to resolve what version of libraries your app actually wants. In other words, you break the tie. But you don’t want to break it every time, so save your choice.

### Bower.json Resolutions

When you run bower install, the resolution process is interactive. When bower recognizes that there are two packages that depend on a package at different versions, it’ll list all those versions and ask:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
    1) ember#~1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and is required by ember-data#0.0.14
    2) ember#1.5.1 which resolved to 1.5.1 and is required by melodrama
```

In this case, the library in question is ember. I can press the number 2 and bower will install the 2nd option, ember#1.5.1.

The next line in the prompt is very handy. It reads:

```
Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Awesome! So, if I type !2 instead, my choice is saved in bower.json.

Now, the next time you run bower install, there is no interactive question of what version I want because I’ve already resolved that ember for my app should be version 1.5.1.

Comment: Pleasure to help you @jonahrchirika. :)